# ERROR building qemu: pthread check failed

Tags: build, pthreads, qemu, debian-buster

I am trying to build qemu on Debian buster for amd64 with `--target-list="i386-softmmu x86_64-softmmu"`.

But getting error

```
ERROR: pthread check failed
       Make sure to have the pthread libs and headers installed.
```

Searched on internet and stackoverflow and checked that I have installed the following libraries that were told to provide the `pthread libs` and `headers`.

```
libc6 libc6-dev libpth-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev
```

What am I missing? Which Debian `package` to install to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Debian based distributions, the easiest way to ensure you have all the build dependencies installed is to make sure your apt sources.list includes deb-src lines, and then use "apt build-dep qemu". This will install everything needed to build the distro's version of QEMU, which is generally pretty much what you want for a build from source.

If you've done that and are still seeing issues: make sure you're building a recent QEMU and not some ancient version.

Comment: Still getting the error: `ERROR: pthread check failed
       Make sure to have the pthread libs and headers installed.`

trying to build `qemu-6.0.0` which I hope is fairly latest.

Comment: There should be a build log produced in config.log which (as well as a lot of irrelevant information) will include more detail on why that check failed.

Comment: I could even compile the program that is given in the configure script to probe pthread. So as a quick hack I commented the `pthreads check` part from the configure script. Which seems to be dealing with MinGW only.

`3469:#  error_exit "pthread check failed" \`

But then I got the error: `ERROR: Unknown target name 'x86_64-softmmu'`

Comment: in the `config.log`

`config-temp/qemu-conf.c:2:2: error: #error __i386__ not defined
 #error __i386__ not defined
  ^~~~~`
this error appears. I tried googling but could not find any way out. Thanks.

Comment: config.log includes lots of compiles of things that don't work, because it's testing for what works and what doesn't. The interesting bit will be at the bottom of the file. And no, you can't just comment out the pthreads check, because QEMU needs pthreads and if the check is going wrong then the whole build isn't going to work.

Comment: Ok. I will recheck again by uncommenting the pthreads check. 

Anyway there was this type of errors also in the config.log


Do you think I have the correct compile options too? AFAIK, I haven't set any compiler flags through the configure options. 


`cc: error: unrecognized command line option �~@~X-Wtautological-type-limit-compare�~@~Y; did you mean �~@~X-Wtautological-compare�~@~Y?

gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0`

Thanks.

Comment: I can't diagnose the problem looking at a one-line-at-a-time letterbox view of the logfile...

Comment: It worked after I changed to the configure option which were conflicting `--target-list and --disable-system`. I removed --disable-system option and it worked. But your help with `apt build-dep qemu` helped. So I am accepting your answer. Hope this comment will be helpful to somebody. Thanks.